# How to check if there are no more documents to update using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I am learning CRUD for a school project and I followed a tutorial that was really useful. However, when I completed it I noticed that when there are no more quotes to update, it still updates quotes. How can I change this so that it will stop updating quotes that arent even there?

```
  app.put('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    quoteCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: 'Yoda' },
      {
        $set: {
          name: req.body.name,
          quote: req.body.quote
        }
      },
      {upsert: true}
    )
    .then(result => {
      //The if block that i am trying
      if (result.deletedCount === 0) {
        return res.json('No quote to delete')
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
  })
```

Comment: It can hardly update records that are not there. The `upsert` option that you specified means that if the entry is not found, it will create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing `{name: "Yoda}`? This route is supposed to only update the quote with "Yoda" as its name? If not, then you need to grab from the request object the quote that should be updated.

I tried to create a different version, based on the assumption that the quote that should be updated will come from the req.body:

```
app.put("/quotes", async (req, res) => {
  //Grab the name/id/identifier for the quote you want to update from the body
  const query = req.body.name;

  // Try to update the document on the database
  try {
    const result = await quoteCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
      query,
      {
        name: req.body.name,
        quote: req.body.quote,
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
      }
    );

    // If it worked, it will return the updated quote
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 200,
      data: {
        result,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 400,
      message: "Something went wrong",
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi lucasmrl, thank you for you're help! I had also figured out that I didnt have a tight understanding on upsert, it isnt needed and getting rid of it actually resolves the issue as well.

Comment: Awesome! Keep coding! ;)